# Qual o melhor tipo de campo? TextField, slider, ...? Para valor acima de 0.1?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Fiz esse layout como exemplo de um problema que estou tendo na criação de um sistema, pois bem, no primeiro campo de valor (`TextField`) não posso deixar que o usuário insira o valor zero, só será permitido 0.1 para cima, como faço para resolver isso?

Queria que fosse permitido apenas 0.1 para cima, pois no momento, está causando erro no sistema.

Cheguei pensar em criar um `Slider`, como na foto, onde o usuário iria apenas mexer no `Slider` a partir do 0.1, porém surgiu outro problema:

Queria que os valores fossem da seguinte forma,

0.1 / 0.5 / 1 / 1.5 / 2 / ...

Como eu poderia fazer isso usando Slider? Fui alterando em *properties* como está na foto, mas sem sucesso.

Nesse caso, qual o melhor tipo de campo? `TextField`, `Slider`, ...? Para valor acima de 0.1? E de preferência, 0.1 / 0.5 / 1 / 1.5 / 2 / ...

<kbd>[image: scene builder com slider, textfield]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alcançar isso usando o componente [Spinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html). Procure ele na aba de componentes do seu SceneBuilder e configure-o dessa forma em seu controller:

```
@FXML
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    SpinnerValueFactory<Double> factory = new SpinnerValueFactory<Double>() {
        @Override
        public void decrement(int steps) {
            Double current = this.getValue();
            if(current - 0.5 > 0.1){
                this.setValue(current - 0.5);
            }else{
                this.setValue(0.1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void increment(int steps) {
            Double current = this.getValue();
            Double newValue = (current == 0.1) ? current + 0.4 : current + 0.5;
            this.setValue(newValue);
        }
    };
    // Define o valor inicial (sem essa linha ocorre NullPointerException)
    factory.setValue(0.1);
    // Define o factory de valores
    spinner.setValueFactory(factory);
}
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado, perfeito..